# Modify label to input

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I need to modify the label that is created in an input form with CakePHP and JQuery.

```
$info = "test";
echo $this->Form->input('tipo_de_venta', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Tipo de venta'.$info, 'div' => 'required', 'options' => $opciones_tipo_venta));
```

What I'm doing is to set a variable `$info` with a default value, and each time you change the select the option to change the value. Depending on the selection

```
$('#tipo_de_venta').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this);
    if(this.value == 1){

    }
    if(this.value == 0){

    }
    if(this.value == 2){

    }
});
```

Try `$(this).text("Change");` but it does not work for me.

Html :

```
<div class="required">
    <label for="EventoTipoDeVenta">Tipo de venta</label>
    <select name="data[Evento][tipo_de_venta]" id="EventoTipoDeVenta">
        <option value="0">Compra simple</option>
        <option value="1">Change</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Compra multiple simplificada</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the initial rendered HTML?

Comment: initial HTML? what do you mean?

Comment: The html of the input and other elements when the page is loaded from page source.

Comment: `$('#tipo_de_venta')` what type is this element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
$('#tipo_de_venta').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this);
    if(this.value == 1){
       $(this).closest('div').find('label').text('One');
    }
    if(this.value == 0){
       $(this).closest('div').find('label').text('zero');
    }
    if(this.value == 2){
       $(this).closest('div').find('label').text('two');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked in my case,

```
$(this).closest('div').find('label').html('Change')
```